# Python crashes without errors

Tags: python, crash, trace

My python code crashes without providing any exceptions. The code uses Tkinter, socket programming, pyvisa, thread, and modules. It is an automated sensor calibration system using python. The code runs on a Windows 10 machine with python version 2.7.16

It is not crashing at a fixed point. The crash is random. 6/10 times the code completes the process, rest it crashes without error. When I use python trace, I can tell with certainty that 10/10 it successful.

When I convert this code into an executable file using auto-py-to-exe, the number of times the crash happens reduces. Now the problem is I need to find out the cause of the issue and then export this code into an executable file. Can someone guide me as to how I can figure out the issue? Also, I run the trace from the command line, is there a way to include this trace in the script so that when I convert the code to an executable I can check if it is crashing.

Comment: You could wrap your outermost code in a try/except and write traceback information to a file. Then reraise so any regular processing happens.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you forgot to add `tkinter.mainloop()` at the end of your code, cause tkinter.mainloop() tells Python to run the Tkinter event loop. This method listens for events, such as button clicks or keypresses

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the --debug option when using auto-py-to-exe?
See the blog post about tool usage, especially the debug section

https://nitratine.net/blog/post/issues-when-using-auto-py-to-exe/?utm_source=auto_py_to_exe&utm_medium=readme_link&utm_campaign=auto_py_to_exe_help